# Get names and links values when looping HTML elements with Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script

I am making a web app for a Spreadsheet for a sidebar.

Trying to handle an event listener that implements these conditions:

- when checking checkboxes (which have correspondent names and Calendar links for that names)
- and picking 2 dates
- and then clicking the button

After it's all done a function is called from backend which gets events for that names and records them to a sheet.

**I can't get the values for names and calendars in a loop**. And not sure what's the good way to put them. I tried to handle it in different ways - no luck.

I eventually narrowed all issues to these 2 parts:

1) how to load data to a sidebar in a best way.

2) how to loop through that data after user interacted with these elements and to get values (depends on the part 1).

I would really appreciate if someone help me a bit more on it (some rather simple solutions).

Here's the variant with scriptlets for using GAS in an html file:

```
<? for (var i = 0; i < loopNamesForSidebar().names.length; i++) {  ?>
    <label>
       <input type="checkbox" class="filled-in check" checked="checked" />
       <span>
         <div class="collection">     
           <a href=" <?= loopNamesForSidebar().calendars[i] ?>" class="collection-item" >
             <?= loopNamesForSidebar().names[i]  ?>
           </a>
         </div>
       </span>
<? } ?>
    </label>
```

`loopNamesForSidebar()` is a backend function which loops names and calendars that go to the sidebar. Every time I open the sidebar this data refreshes. I don't have it used in my front-end part.

Here's a Javascript code in an html file:

```js
   //import jobs from calendars to sheet 
function importJobs() {
  //getting all checkboxes
  var allCheckboxes = document.getElementsByClassName("check")

  //getting inputs of start and end dates
  var startDate = document.getElementById("startDate").value
  var endDate = document.getElementById("endDate").value

  var chosenNames = []
  var calendars = []

  //looping all checkboxes
  for (var i = 0; i < allCheckboxes.length; i++) {
    //getting value of each checkbox
    var checkbox = allCheckboxes[i].checked;

    //if checkbox is checked
    if (checkbox == true) {
      //getting correspondant employee name
      var name = loopNamesForSidebar().names[i]

      //and push it to an array
      chosenNames.push(name)

      //getting correspondant employee calendar
      var cal = loopNamesForSidebar().calendars[i]
      calendars.push(cal)

    } else {
      continue;
    }
  };

  //push names and cals to object
  var employees = {
    names: chosenNames,
    cals: calendars
  }

  //call function to get calendar events
  google.script.run.getEvents(employees, startDate, endDate)
};
```

Comment: For starters, you're going to have much better performance if you just call `loopNamesForSidebars` once. Your scriptlet version is calling it a LOT, in its entirety. Also note that scriptlets are only applicable in the evaluation of the initial `HtmlTemplate` object - they aren't dynamically evaluated while your sidebar is loaded.

Comment: True! The execution is really slow. So you are saying it's a bad practice to use scriptlets to get elements? Thanks for the tip.

Comment: What that means is you cannot use the defined-in-gs server function `loopNamesForSidebar` in your client-side function `importJobs`. You can *call it*, via `google.script.run`, and receive the results in whichever *success handler* you bind to the `google.script.run` invocation.

Comment: It's absolutely recommended to load only static content in your initial `HtmlTemplate` / `HtmlOutput` - i.e. only things retrieved from `PropertiesService` or `CacheService`, or trivially computed based on input `doGet` / `doPost` parameters. Anything requiring an API / Service call should be loaded asynchronously. https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/best-practices#load_data_asynchronously_not_in_templates

Comment: The reason why I have been looping these names on each sidebar opening is that this data is changing time to time. Some people come and go and I can't use statis data once and forever. I want to make sure that I open the sidebar and the data there is always actual and I don't need to remember to reload it there somehow etc.

Comment: You've helped me narrow my issues to only two parts: 1) how to load actual data to a sidebar in a best way 2) how to loop through them and get values (depends on the part 1). I would really appreciate if someone help me a bit more on it.

Comment: I am studying your reference but not fully got yet. Can you give an example of how I can load ~ 30 names (let's say static data) with 30 corresponding checkboxes to a sidebar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per [Best Practices](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/best-practices#load_data_asynchronously_not_in_templates), you should load any API / ___ Service call output asynchronously. I would only use template evaluation for trivially computed / retrieved data, e.g. from `PropertiesService`, `CacheService`, static definitions, or simple lookups based on input parameters (i.e. querystring / payload data for `doGet` and `doPost` trigger functions). If it takes longer than a quarter second on average, it's too slow for synchronous usage.

so:

```
function templateOK(param) {
  const val = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().getProperty(param);
  return val ? JSON.parse(val) : [
    "name 1", "name 2", "name 3"
  ];
}
function shouldRunAsync(param) {
  const sheet = param ? SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName(param) : null;
  return sheet ? sheet.getDataRange().getValues() : [];
}
```

Assuming you've set up the other parts of your GS and HTML files appropriately, one of the .html's `<script>` tags may look something like this:

```
$(document).ready(() => loadServerData()); // jQuery
function loadServerData() {
  const TASK = google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(useNames); // has implicit failure handler of `console`
  // Schedule this to be run every so often
  const intervalMS = 10 * 60 * 1000; // 10 minutes
  setInterval(sheetName => TASK.shouldRunAsync(sheetName), intervalMS, "Names");
  // Invoke promptly too.
  TASK.shouldRunAsync("Names");
  console.log(new Date(), "Set schedule & invoked server function");
}
function useNames(serverValue, userObject) {
  console.log(new Date(), "Got Value from server", serverValue);
  // use the return value to do stuff, e.g.
  const cbDiv = $("id of div containing checkboxes"); // jQuery
  /** could add code here to read existing checkbox data, and
      use that to maintain checked/unchecked state throughout loads */
  cbDiv.innerHTML = serverValue.map((name, idx) => `<p id="${name}">${idx + 1}: ${name}</p>`).join("");
}
```

As always, make sure you are intimately familiar with the serializable data types and the Client-Server communication model: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/communication

Other refs

- [`Element#innerHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML)
- [`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)
- [`setInterval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setInterval)
- [Arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)
- [Template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)

Comment: Thank you so much @tehhowch!!! You've helped a lot saving days of vain practice))

Comment: How do you test and debug html part? I use html checker to check tags but that doesn't help to check the logic as much as the debugger.